# Hosting a Prism app using UnityBootStrapper in a WindowsForms project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, prism

How to host a WPF Prism app using UnityBootStrapper in a WindowsForms project?

I have added references to below wpf assemblies in the Windows forms host project

```
PresentationCore 
PresentationFramework 
WindowsBase Ayatem.xaml 
WindowsFormsIntegration.dll 
Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions
```

And I have deleted the app.xaml file of Prism project. 
In the ElementHost control of win forms, I am trying to populate shell but, it doesn't load the module.

```
//Create the ElementHost control for hosting the WPF UserControl
ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
host.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

//Create the WPF UserControl.
HelloWorld.Shell uc = new HelloWorld.Shell();

//Assign the WPF UserControl to the ElementHost control's Child property.
host.Child = uc;

//Add the ElementHost control to the form's collection of child controls.
this.Controls.Add(host);
```

I am using the hello world sample prism application and as of today, my project has only 1 module.

Answer (score 0):

The following ***Codeplex's*** discussion resolves a quite similar scenario to the one you would try to accomplish:

- [Prism4 in Windows Forms environment](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/272418)

Notice that you would need to modify the ***ReionManager's IsInDesignMode()*** method from the **Prism.Desktop** project as a fix has been implemented for a known issue when using *Cider*. You would just need to change the method, rebuild the **Prism Library** and reference the newly built assemblies into your ***WinForm*** solution.

I hope this helped,
Regards.